# HTML5 video - onmuted and onloop event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-video

How to detect the switching of muted and loop properties of a video?

There are no "onmuted" or "onloop" events, as "onplay" or "onpause", unfortunately.

Object.observe doesn't work.
MutationObserver doesn't work either.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You can detect `muted` with a "volumechange" event.

```
video.addEventListener('volumechange', function () {
    console.log('muted', video.muted);
}, false);
// video.onvolumechange = ... works too
```

2) MutationObserver doesn't work muted because there's no attribute for it, but it *does* work for `loop`.

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if (mutation.type === 'attribute' && mutation.attributeName === 'loop') {
            console.log('loop changed', video.loop);
        }
    });
});

observer.observe(video, {
    attributes: true
});
```

In my testing, the observer callback fires whether you set `video.loop = true` with Javascript (at least in Chrome and Firefox) or with the right-click dropdown menu (not available in FF, just Chrome) on the video element.